# How to monitor and control DPU usage in AWS Glue Crawlers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

In [the docs](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/pricing/) it's said that AWS allocates by default 10 DPUs per ETL job and 5 DPUs per development endpoint by default, even though both can have a minimum of 2 DPUs configured.

It's also mentioned that Crawling is also priced on second increments and with a 10 minute minimum run, but nowhere is specified how many DPUs are allocated. Jobs and Development Endpoints can be configured in the Glue console to consume less DPUs, but I haven't seen any such configuration for the crawlers.

Is there a fixed amount of DPUs per crawler? Can we control that amount?

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible for now to control Crawler's DPU

Comment: Yes, Alexey is correct, as for now, its not possible to modify the Crawler DPUs or view the DPU details for crawlers.

Comment: Any update on this? Very interest in how to track costs, especially since tagging is not supported with Glue service.

Comment: I am getting a minimum cost for a very quick crawler of £0.01782, which is about $0.023. Based on a 10 minute minimum run, and a hourly cost of $0.44 per DPU, I worked out I am using 0.023*6/0.44 = 0.3 of a DPU during the run. This is approx 1.25 vCPU and 5GB memory.

Answer (score 5):

This is my conversation with AWS Support about this subject:

> Hello, I'd like to know how many DPUs a crawler uses in order to
> calculate my costs with crawlers.

Their answer:

> Dear AWS Customer,
>
> Thank you for reaching out today. My name is Safari, I will assist
> with your case.
>
> I understand that while compiling the cost of your Glue crawlers,
> you'd like to know the amount of DPUs a particular crawler uses.
>
> Unfortunately, there is no direct way to find out the DPU consumption
> by a given crawler. I apologize for the inconvenience. However, you
> may see the total DPU consumption across all crawlers in your detailed
> bill under the section AWS Service Charges > Glue > {region} > AWS
> Glue CrawlerRun. Additionally, you can add tags to your crawlers and
> then enable "Cost Allocation Tags" from your AWS Billing and Cost
> Management console. This would allow AWS to generate a cost allocation
> report grouped by the predefined tags. For more on this, please see
> the documentation link below [1].
>
> I hope this helps. Please let me know if I can provide you with any
> other assistance.
>
> References [1]:
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html

Answer (score 3):

Discussed with AWS support team as well, and currently its not possible to modify or view the DPU configuration details for Glue - crawlers. But, does crawlers use a DPU?

Comment: Yes they do, and they're charged exactly alike Jobs except that it's not transparent how many DPUs they will or did consume.